# Why does the caret appear thicker on some sites?

Tags: html, css, textbox, caret

Some sites are using a bigger caret in Chrome. For example, on Stack Overflow:

[image: thick caret screenshot]

Others, such as Google, don't:

[image: thin caret screenshot]

I can't see anything that appears to define this in the element inspector. How is this done?

Comment: I am on MacOSX w/ Chrome 21 and don't notice what you are showing. Not sure if you can edit the cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a byproduct of changing the font size, and probably drawing a "thicker" line as a result of subpixel rendering. You can't directly change it, and you absolutely shouldn't care about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom cursor, which you can download or create on your own.

Then put this in your CSS:

```
cursor: url("customCursor.cur");
```

Comment: That changes the mouse cursor, not the caret.